# Leaflet.js TypeError: t is undefined with multiple maps

Tags: jquery, leaflet

I'm trying to display three maps on one page with leaflet.js and mapquests API. I've created a jQuery `for-loop` to read a unique postal code, then convert it (via mapquest) to latitude and longitude, and lastly create three maps, and add the matching latitude and longitude to every map. This would then result in three different maps, displayed on one page.

I've somewhat achieved this with the code below. Every "card" has its own card number (from 1 to 3), postal code, and corresponding map and map ID.

*Edit* I also get this jQuery error:

```
jQuery.Deferred exception: t is undefined addTo@https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.js:5:64070
MYWEBSITEURL/map.js:38:6
e@https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2:30005
l/</t<@https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2:30307
 undefined
```

The issue I now have is that when my jQuery runs I get this console error: `TypeError: t is undefined`. I've narrowed it down to it having something to do with either the `L.tileLayer()` and/or `L.circle()` functions. I've added the latest jQuery and leaflet.js to the page.

*Edit* Changed the question after @ivansanchez answer, but still the same issues.

*Edit* Changed the `leaflet.js` to `leaflet-sr.js` and I now get the error: `TypeError: map is undefined`

map.js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var postalCodes = [];
var latLng      = [];
var lat         = [];
var lng         = [];
var maps        = [];

for(var n = 0; n < 3; n++) {

    console.log('Maps for-loop count: '+n);

    postalCodes.push($('.card'+[n]+' .card__info--postal > span').html());

    $.ajax({ // Get lat & long from postal code
        async: false,
        url: 'https://www.mapquestapi.com/geocoding/v1/address?key=MYAPIKEY&postalCode='+postalCodes[n]+'&country=finland',
        success: function(obj) {
            latLng[n] = obj.results[0].locations[0].latLng;
            lat[n]    = latLng[n].lat;
            lng[n]    = latLng[n].lng;
        },
        error: function(xhr) {
            console.log('Map error', xhr);
        }
    });

    console.log(latLng[n], lat[n], lng[n]);

    var map = L.map('mapid'+[n]).setView([lat[n], lng[n]], 13);

    L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token={accessToken}', {
        maxZoom: 18,
        id: 'mapbox/streets-v11',
        tileSize: 512,
        zoomOffset: -1,
        accessToken: 'MYAPIKEY'
    }).addTo(maps[n]);

    L.circle([lat[n], lng[n]], { // Map out area of the postal code
        color: 'rgb(218, 65, 103)',
        fillColor: 'rgb(218, 65, 103)',
        fillOpacity: 0.5,
        radius: 500
    }).addTo(maps[n]);

    maps.push(map);
}
});
```

Comment: Why `JSON.stringify` the lat and lng? You end up with a string that won't parse in `L.circle`. Inspect what you actually get in `latLng[n]` and process accordingly.

Comment: I had an issue with the code earlier and fixed it with stringify. I removed it, but still the same error.

Comment: So what do you get in `latLng[n]` ?

Comment: @peeebeee An object ex. `Object { lat: 12.345, lng: 12.345 }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing...

```
 var maps = [ L.map('mapid'+[n]).setView([lat[n], lng[n]], 13) ]; // Creates three maps, that corresponds with three mapids in my HTML
```

...and that doesn't do what you think it does. You're creating an array of **one** element, and assigning it to `maps`, and you're doing that three times. Therefore, at the second pass of the loop, when the code refers to `maps[1]`, that has an `undefined` value.

Instead, you probably want to do something like...

```
var maps = [];
for(var n = 0; n < 3; n++) {
   /* stuff */
   maps.push( L.map( /*stuff*/ ) );
   L.tileLayer( /* stuff */ ).addTo(maps[n]);
}
```

...or even...

```
var maps = [];
for(var n = 0; n < 3; n++) {
   /* stuff */
   var map = L.map( /*stuff*/ );
   L.tileLayer( /* stuff */ ).addTo(map);
   maps.push(map);
}
```

On the other hand, you have a good ol' [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition#Software) regarding the values of `latLng[n]`, `lat[n]` and `lng[n]`. Since those values are only set when the network operation has finished (since AJAX is async, etc etc), they are (most probably) `undefined` when they are used. You might want to delay adding data to each map until you actually got said data, like e.g.

```
var maps = [];
for(var n = 0; n < 3; n++) {
   var map = L.map( /*stuff*/ );
   fetch(url)
     .then(function(response){return response.json})
     .then(function(json)){
       L.circle(json.results[0].locations[0]).addTo(map);
     });
   L.tileLayer( /* stuff */ ).addTo(map);
   maps.push(map);
}
```

Note that the sequence of events here is: a network request is *initiated*, the map is instantiated, the tilelayer is instantiated, the network request completes, the circle gets instantiated.

(And why yes, I prefer [the fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) over jQuery any day).

Remember that, in Leaflet, it's usually nice to change `leaflet.js` into `leaflet-src.js` to get better stack traces, and that using the browser's developer tools to set breakpoints prior to exceptions will allow you to see which values are `undefined` at that time.

Comment: Thx for the answer, @ivansanchez I tried to change the code like your example #2, declaring the `maps` array first and then using `.push` to add each map. But I still have the same issue. I've updated the code on the question to what I now have. I still get: `jQuery.Deferred exception: t is undefined addTo@https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.js:5:64070` and `TypeError: t is undefined`. The `latLng[n]`, `lat[n]` and `lng[n]` are not `undefined` when I try to `console.log(latLng[n], lat[n], lng[n])` them inside the `for-loop`

Comment: Do a `console(n)` inside the ajax `sucess` callback, then wonder why that's happening, then read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work

Comment: It loops just once, as the entire loop does. If I comment out the `L.titleLayer` and `L.circle` the loop finishes, and I get three `postalcodes`, `latLng` objects and three different maps. I changed the `leaflet.js` to `leaflet-src.js` and I now get the error of: `TypeError: map is undefined`

Comment: Ahh now I see, stupid me I had the old `addTo(maps[n])` instead of your `addTo(map)`

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to:

```
maps[n] = L.map('mapid'+[n]).setView([lat[n], lng[n]], 13);
```

Comment: Any other clues to my issue?